# Opendaylight - Unable to join cluster

Tags: apache-karaf, opendaylight, akka-cluster

We recently moved to Nitrogen-SR3 and we have customized clustering with 2 node. When we restart a node (ie., after failback), we observe following exception in karaf.log and the node is unable to join the cluster. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Connection attempt failed
        at org.opendaylight.controller.cluster.databroker.actors.dds.AbstractShardBackendResolver.wrap(AbstractShardBackendResolver.java:129)[505:org.opendaylight.controller.sal-distributed-datastore:1.6.3]
        at org.opendaylight.controller.cluster.databroker.actors.dds.AbstractShardBackendResolver.lambda$connectShard$2(AbstractShardBackendResolver.java:142)[505:org.opendaylight.controller.sal-distributed-datastore:1.6.3]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:760)[:1.8.0_66]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:736)[:1.8.0_66]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.exec(CompletableFuture.java:443)[:1.8.0_66]
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)[:1.8.0_66]
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)[:1.8.0_66]
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)[:1.8.0_66]
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)[:1.8.0_66]
Caused by: org.opendaylight.controller.cluster.access.concepts.RetiredGenerationException: Originating generation was superseded by 3
at org.opendaylight.controller.cluster.datastore.Shard.findFrontend(Shard.java:482)[505:org.opendaylight.controller.sal-distributed-datastore:1.6.3]
        at org.opendaylight.controller.cluster.datastore.Shard.handleConnectClient(Shard.java:522)[505:org.opendaylight.controller.sal-distributed-datastore:1.6.3]
        at org.opendaylight.controller.cluster.datastore.Shard.handleNonRaftCommand(Shard.java:325)[505:org.opendaylight.controller.sal-distributed-datastore:1.6.3]
        at org.opendaylight.controller.cluster.raft.RaftActor.handleCommand(RaftActor.java:270)[490:org.opendaylight.controller.sal-akka-raft:1.6.3]
        at org.opendaylight.controller.cluster.common.actor.AbstractUntypedPersistentActor.onReceiveCommand(AbstractUntypedPersistentActor.java:44)[498:org.opendaylight.controller.sal-clustering-commons:1.6.3]
        at akka.persistence.UntypedPersistentActor.onReceive(PersistentActor.scala:170)[321:com.typesafe.akka.persistence:2.4.20]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are hitting this [open bug](https://jira.opendaylight.org/browse/CONTROLLER-1742)

Comment: We also observe following bundle takes more time to transition from "GracePeriod" to "Active" state.


(mdsal-eos-binding-adapter and
mdsal-singleton-dom-impl)

Comment: We observe some code changes being committed, can we know what is the root cause for this issue.

Comment: you should be interacting with the jira ticket to get more details like root cause, etc. just post a comment/question there.

Comment: We observe Opendaylight bundles are waiting indefinitely in "GracePeriod" state, but for our application bundles we notices bundles transition to "Failure" state after 5min, could you please let us know how to increase the timeout similar to ODL bundles